# jQuery.ajax url: rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my code I have this button

```html
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="check_module">Pay</button>
```

when clicked on iframe opens from this javascript code

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://service.iamport.kr/js/iamport.payment-1.1.5.js"></script>

<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $("#check_module").click(function () {
    IMP.init(''); //iamport 대신 자신의 "가맹점 식별코드"를 사용하시면 됩니다
    IMP.request_pay({
      merchant_uid : "<%= @merchant_uid %>",
      name : '결제테스트',
      amount : <%= @price %>,
      buyer_email : '<%= current_user.email %>',
      buyer_name : '<%= current_user.name %>',
      buyer_tel : ' no phone ',
      buyer_addr : ' course name: no address',
      buyer_postcode : ' no postcode ',
      m_redirect_url: "https://url"
    }, function(rsp) {
      if ( rsp.success ) {// Successful payment: Successful payment approval or issuance of a virtual account
      // HTTP request using jQuery
      jQuhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#ery.ajax({
          url: "<%= payment_complete_path(:item_id => @item) %>", // Merchant server
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          data: {
              imp_uid: rsp.imp_uid,
              merchant_uid: rsp.merchant_uid
          }
      }).done(function (data) {

        // Logic executed on successful response from the merchant server through the payment API
      })
      } else {
        var msg = '결제에 실패하였습니다.';
        msg += '에러내용 : ' + rsp.error_msg;
      }
    });
  });
<% end %>
```

but after submitting the form the transaction goes through successfully
but it stays on the page

how can I make it to go to this url or this action

```
          url: "<%= payment_complete_path(:item_id => @item) %>", // Merchant server
```

in my controller ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Post the route for payment_complete_path

Comment: post  'payment_complete', :to => 'enrollments#payment_complete', :as => 'payment_comeplete' Is this what you mean?